# ASP.NET Core 8.0 : is there is any other way to route web API besides using parameters within the API Controller?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-8

How can I route my API controllers using `program.cs` instead of using parameters within the controller itself?

This is my `HomeController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace project.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Home()
        {
            var person = new
            {
                LastName = "Atem",
                FirstName = "Yummi"
            };
            return Ok(person);
        }
    }
}
```

And instead of using

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

I'm trying to map each controller action with `app.UseEndpoints()`.

I tried this but it doesn't work - here is my `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Topaz.Server.Controllers;
[assembly: ApiController]
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var ReactAppAllowence = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(ReactAppAllowence,
                          policy =>
                          {
                              policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5173").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                          });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(ReactAppAllowence);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/api/home", async context =>
    {
        // Handle the request by calling the corresponding controller method.
        var controller = new HomeController(); // Create an instance of your controller
        var result = controller.Home(); // Call the desired method

        // Return the result (serialized if needed)
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(result);
    });
});
app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: i'm familiar with symfony framework and all the routing there can be mapped from a YAML file and i wonder if it's possible to map my web api  using program.cs instead each time declaring the parameter [Route("api/[controller]")] or  [HttpGet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can learn what @Kiksen said about minimal api.

[Tutorial: Create a minimal API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Then, I need explain to you that the `pattern` in MapGet depends on which route you typed in the browser and it would hit the minimal api instead of any controller action route.

At last, for not working of your code, you need change your code to:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/api/home", async context =>
    {
        // Handle the request by calling the corresponding controller method.
        var controller = new HomeController(); // Create an instance of your controller
        var result = controller.Home(); // Call the desired method

        //change here.....
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)result).Value);      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow microsoft docs. Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-api-code

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoDb>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/todoitems", async (TodoDb db) =>
    await db.Todos.ToListAsync());

app.MapGet("/todoitems/complete", async (TodoDb db) =>
    await db.Todos.Where(t => t.IsComplete).ToListAsync());

app.MapGet("/todoitems/{id}", async (int id, TodoDb db) =>
    await db.Todos.FindAsync(id)
        is Todo todo
            ? Results.Ok(todo)
            : Results.NotFound());

app.MapPost("/todoitems", async (Todo todo, TodoDb db) =>
{
    db.Todos.Add(todo);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.Created($"/todoitems/{todo.Id}", todo);
});

app.MapPut("/todoitems/{id}", async (int id, Todo inputTodo, TodoDb db) =>
{
    var todo = await db.Todos.FindAsync(id);

    if (todo is null) return Results.NotFound();

    todo.Name = inputTodo.Name;
    todo.IsComplete = inputTodo.IsComplete;

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.NoContent();
});

app.MapDelete("/todoitems/{id}", async (int id, TodoDb db) =>
{
    if (await db.Todos.FindAsync(id) is Todo todo)
    {
        db.Todos.Remove(todo);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.NoContent();
    }

    return Results.NotFound();
});

app.Run();
```